# Regex lookaround to find anything up to an already searched group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to analyze search queries of a particular pattern.

The pattern is:

> How many/much _____ is/are _____.

Given this pattern, the blanks are unknown to me but I want to extract any statement that follows this pattern above.

My challenge is finding a way to do a lookaround on is/are up to but not including many/much and anything after but not including is/are.

Here's my regex so far:

```
(([hH]ow many?)|([hH]ow much?))|(?<=is)|(are)|(i|s|n|a|o|f){1,2}|((\")|(\“)|(\/)|(\'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this regex with the `i` flag to match case insensitive

```
^how\s+(?:much|many)\s+(.*?)\s(?:is|are)\s+(.*?)[.?]?$
```

Then it'll match these strings

```
How much bla is blabla.
How many bla are blablabla?
```

And the bla's will be in capture group 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(?<=[Hh]ow\smany\s|[Hh]ow\smuch\s)(.+)(?=\sis|\sare)|(?<=is\s|are\s)(.+)/g
```

Review it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p03UWu/1)

Lookarounds are placed behind and/or ahead of your capture group:

**1st Capture Group**

```
(?<=[Hh]ow\smany\s|[Hh]ow\smuch\s) /* "(H|h)ow"\space"many"\space OR 
                                      "(H|h)ow"\space"much"\space 
                                      must be before capture group */
(.+)               /* capture group one or more of anything */
(?=\sis|\sare)     /* \space"is" OR \space"are" must be after capture group */
```

```
|                  // OR
```

**2nd Capture Group**

```
(?<=is\s|are\s)    /* "is"\space OR "are\space must be before capture group */
(.+)               /* capture group one or more of anything */
```

Answer (score 0):

If both parts for the `_____` are mandatory you could use 2 capture groups:

```
\b[Hh]ow\s+(?:much|many)\s+(\S.*?)\s+(?:is|are)\s+([^.]+)\.
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[Hh]ow\s+` Match `How` or `how` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:much|many)\s+` Match either `much` or `many` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)\s+` Capture in **group 1** at least a single non whitespace char, then as least as possible chars and match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:is|are)\s+` Match either `is` or `are` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `([^.]+)` Capture in **group 2** 1+ chars other than a dot
- `\.` Match a dot

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i1n95m/1).